# Need Jinja2 templates to work on Windows github runner

Tags: windows, templates, environment-variables, jinja2, github-actions

I have the following file in my repo containing variables that should be evaluated after checkout.

```
cat infra/.env_qa

myname="Appone_${{ inputs.component }}"
port="8814"
server_list="{{ secrets.deploy_pass }}"
....
```

https://github.com/cuchi/jinja2-action

I use Jinja templates to generate a new file with the values as below:

```
- name: Setup env file
  uses: cuchi/jinja2-action@v1.2.0
  with:
    template: infra/.env_qa.j2
    output_file: infra/.env_qa
```

Unfortunately, this action runs only on Linux while I have a Windows runner.

I would like to know

1. Alternate Jinja template action that runs on Windows
2. How can I determine if an action is designed to run on Windows or not without running it.

Comment: 1. You can search on the [GitHub Actions Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions). 2. [Docker based actions are supported only on Linux](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/about-custom-actions#types-of-actions) so you can identify them from their `action.yml` file and look for `runs` section. See [here](https://github.com/cuchi/jinja2-action/blob/3fa06acb38601d3caea4c5ce0416e268a8799d71/action.yml#L21-L23).

Comment: As a workaround, you can run that action under `ubuntu-latest` in a separate job, upload the generated file as an artifact, and then download it under your window job.

Comment: Or, you can directly use [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) from the command line without that action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Alternate Jinja template action that runs on Windows?

You can search on the [GitHub Actions Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions).

As a workaround, you can run that action under `ubuntu-latest` in a separate job, upload the generated file as an artifact, and then download it under your Windows job. Or, you can directly use [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) from the command line.

> 2. How can I determine if an action is designed to run on Windows or not without running it?

[Docker based actions are supported only on Linux](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/about-custom-actions#types-of-actions). You can identify them from their `action.yml` file and look for `runs` section e.g. see [here](https://github.com/cuchi/jinja2-action/blob/3fa06acb38601d3caea4c5ce0416e268a8799d71/action.yml#L21-L23).